# how to remove page reload

Tags: asp.net

In my application when we click on add button a Modal PopUp Extender appears in that their are 2 asp button Save and Cancel. When we click on these buttons the page gets reloaded i have to stop it.
Plz help ..

Comment: You want to stop it from posting the result?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax.  How you go about this depends wholy on your design.  Without Ajax, you need to post the page and have it reload.  Ajax still *performs* the posting of the data, but it's behind the scenes from the user point of view, and you need to write scripts to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an UpdatePanel to your aspx-markup and set the buttons as AsyncPostbackTriggers, this will cause only the content of the popup to reload, not the complete page.

The result will look something like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="submitButton" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<!--popup-->
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```